# Terratrike tour II 24 gear cycle

Tags: gears

I need advice on what type chain to replace old chain. Front derailleur 3 gears, rear derailleur 8 gears.

Answer (score 1):

That's an 8 speed 3/32" chain.

Comment: And you likely need three of them. More accurately, about 2.5, but they're very rarely sold that way.

Comment: @Móż I was going for the shortest useful answer, and didn't realise it was a recumbent.   On the plus side, three chains should last three times as long as one ?

Comment: Generally, yes. Conveniently, about the same as an 8 speed cassette :)